# Cut Copy Selected Range At the last cell in a column

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have written a code in which I try to copy and paste several ranges of data from one worksheet to the other, but I want to copy the data below the previous set of data.  The code I used for the copy entries is this part:

```
Selection.Copy

Windows(Workbook1).Activate

Sheets(Sheet1).Select

Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Select

ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

I get the error on the 4th row

> (Application Defined or object Defined error).

Comment: No need to select, Copy and Paste... Do you really want to copy the range based of a selection? If yes, in which column of the second workbook would you like to paste? Does your selection contain only a column?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be condensed using the example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D4").Copy destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E5")
```

Applied to your work:

```
Dim lRow As Long
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim Sourcews As Worksheet: Set Sourcews = wb.Worksheets("Sheet21")
Dim Destinationws As Worksheet: Set Destinationws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

lRow = Destinationws.Cells(Destinationws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Sourcews.Range("A1:D4").Copy Destination:=Destinationws.Range("A" & lRow)
```

> Avoid using activate and select. It is slow and can be unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, please. It will copy the selected range values in the last empty row of column A:A. I deduced that from your way of trying to calculate. But, you did that in an incorrect way. You would copy your range over the "A1:A" & last cell range. Is that what you really want?

```
Sub testCopyValues()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, rng As Range

 Set rng = Selection
 Set sh = Workbooks("Workbook1").Sheets(1)

 lastRow = sh.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row

 sh.Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Resize(rng.Rows.count, rng.Columns.count).Value = rng.Value
End Sub
```

If you need to paste on another sheet of the same workbook, please replace

`Set sh = Workbooks("Workbook1").Sheets(1)` with `Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)`